# Converting a recursive definition to an explicit one

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorial-identities, co.combinatorics

Is there an explicit form for $a_x$ (whole numbers x) given that $a_x = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{x-1} \binom{x-1}{i} a_i$?

I've listed out the first few terms:

for $x=0,1,2,3,4,5,6, 7$

we have $a_x =1, 1, 2, 5, 15, 52, 203, 877$ respectively which shows no obvious pattern, except growing extremely quickly.

Answer (score 4):

You are computing the [Bell numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_numbers).

Answer (score 2):

These are Bell numbers, [A000110](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C1%2C2%2C5%2C15%2C52&language=english&go=Search). The relatively explicit formula given in the Encyclopedia: $$a_n=\frac{2n!}{\pi e}\Im\left(\int_{0}^{\pi} e^{e^{e^{ix}}} \sin(nx) dx \right)$$